# How can I make dynamically changing functions?

Tags: functions

I am trying to do transfer matrix calculations (optics), where I have a layered sample and want to calculate how light propagates through it, depending on some parameters:

[image]

The charm of the method is that you can do a matrix multiplication for every subsequent layer, no matter how many layers you have; you just need a transition matrix `T` between every layer and a propagation matrix `P` for passing through the layer, which can be easily defined. An exemplary transfer matrix of a single layer with air on both sides would look like this:
`M[some properties] := T[air properties,layer properties].P[layer properties].T[layer properties,air properties]`

What I want to do now is a script, where you can give a number of layers such as `n=3` and the transfer matrix will be automatically generated (of course you have to give a list of parameters as well).
I thought of doing this recursively with a for-loop, such as:

```
For[i=1, i<n+1, i++, M[..] := M[..].P[properties i].T[properties i, properties i+1]];
```

but this does not seem to work, probably because I am declaring a function M and then overwrite it (M is initialized as a unity matrix before this function).

The thing is, for a higher number of layers the transition matrix becomes a bit unhandy, and even more so if you want to edit it manually. I was hoping to generate this function dynamically from the input of `n` and a list of material properties and then store it in a file, to be able to transfer it to a different script later.

Is there a way to do this? Where did I go wrong? I know that `:=` is used to delay the calculation of the value (effectively making the thing left of it a function) and that does not seem suited for recursive use... but I also tried different variations and nothing worked. 
Also, the input parameters of the function in the brackets `M[...]` will probably be a problem, because it will be more parameters for each layer. Can I bridge this? I know that I can input anything into a function but I need to name it, because I need the values at specific points of the function.

Somehow I can't believe that Mathematica does not support the dynamic generation of functions depending on input, it seems like such an obvious thing to me. I tried to search for solutions but the name of the `Dynamic[]` function interferes with my search and I couldn't think of a better word to describe the type of function that I want.

**EDIT:**
so here is some real code:

```
P[K_, e_, Q_, d_] := ...
T[K_, ea_, eb_, Q_] := ...

M[K_,Q_,e1_,d1_,e2_] := T[K,e0,e1[K],Q].P[K,e1[K],Q,d1].T[K,e1[K],e2[K],Q];

M[K_,Q_,e1_,d1_,e2_,d2_,e3_] := T[K,e0,e1[K],Q].P[K,e1[K],Q,d1].T[K,e1[K],e2[K],Q].P[K,e2[K],Q,d2].T[K,e2[K],e3[K],Q];

M[K_,Q_,e1_,d1_,e2_,d2_,e3_,d3_,e4_] := T[K,e0,e1[K],Q].P[K,e1[K],Q,d1].T[K,e1[K],e2[K],Q].P[K,e2[K],Q,d2].T[K,e2[K],e3[K],Q].P[K,e3[K],Q,d3].T[K,e3[K],e4[K],Q];
```

these three examples are:

1. air - layer 1 - substrate
2. air - layer 1 - layer 2 - substrate
3. air - layer 1 - layer 2 - layer 3 - substrate

**EDIT 2:**
I tried it this way now:

```
P[K_, e_, Q_, d_] := ...;
T[K_, ea_, eb_, Q_] := ...;

M[K_, Q_, e_, d_, m_] :=  T[K, 1, e[[1, K]], Q].For[i = 1, i < m + 1, i++, P[K, e[i, K], Q, d[i]].T[K, e[i, K], e[i + 1, K], Q].];

e = {e1, e2, e3, e4};
d = {d1, d2, d3};
n = 3;

M[Kvalue, Qvalue, e, d, n]
```

So if only this Matrix multiplication would work with a loop, I would be fine :/ but unfortunately, it doesn't seem to work this way.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!
Best,
Julian

Comment: Why couldn't you use `Piecewise[]`?

Comment: I don't really see how I could use `Piecewise[]` to get the desired result. Would you test for `n` and then return a different function for each `n`? If so, I would have to put in all options manually as far as I can see.
Also, can I put a function definition with arguments in there? I didn't find an example of that in the documentation...

Comment: Could you give us a complete example for, say, two layers? at the moment, the question is a bit fuzzy and, although I understand your physical problem in general, I do not know exactly what you need to do *in Mathematica* so I can't help much.

Comment: You are trying to modify a function so it generates different matrices based on the layer correct? Couldn't you just write a second function that calls M with the different parameters for each layer? Also, are you aware of `Function`?

Comment: @MarcoB I edited the post to include real code (even thought I changed some things, it should represent it adequately).

Comment: @flinty I am not sure how I would write this second function. That's basically what I was trying to do with the For-loop. Just calling `M` for each layer doesn't really work because `M` includes the substrate and superstrate as well...
I was not familiar with `Function[]` and am looking it up at the moment. However, I cannot immediately see the advantages as compared to a declaration via `:=` ... could you comment on that?

Comment: So one quick thought: I could get rid of the additional arguments of the function by using nested lists for `e` and `d`. For example: `e = {e1,e2,e3,...}`and `d = {d1, d2, d3,...}`, where `ei` are lists of index `K`as needed for the Matrix `M` and `di` are just thickness values. When I do a For-loop over `i` as I proposed in my question, I could call them as  `e[[i,K]]` and `d[i]`, probably.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to modify functions, you just need to define the `e[i, K]` and `d[i, K]` and call this:

```
M[K_, Q_, n_] := 
 Fold[Dot, T[K, e0, e[1, K], Q], 
  P[K, e[#, K], Q, d[#, K]].T[K, e[#, K], e[# + 1, K], Q] & /@ Range[n]]

M[K, Q, 1] 
(* returns T[K, e0, e[1, K], Q].P[K, e[1, K], Q, d[1, K]].T[K, e[1, K], e[2, K], Q] *)


M[K, Q, 2] 
(* returns T[K, e0, e[1, K], Q].P[K, e[1, K], Q, d[1, K]].T[K, e[1, K], e[2, K], 
  Q].P[K, e[2, K], Q, d[2, K]].T[K, e[2, K], e[3, K], Q] *)


M[K, Q, 3] 
(* returns T[K, e0, e[1, K], Q].P[K, e[1, K], Q, d[1, K]].T[K, e[1, K], e[2, K], 
  Q].P[K, e[2, K], Q, d[2, K]].T[K, e[2, K], e[3, K], Q].P[K, e[3, K],
   Q, d[3, K]].T[K, e[3, K], e[4, K], Q] *)
```

Comment: I didn't know you could use `Dot` like this... that looks very elegant and exactly what I wanted to do! I will try it out tomorrow and let you know if this works like I want it to. Thanks!

Comment: Did this work for you and is my answer acceptable?

Comment: Sorry, as I simplified the problem a bit for this question I needed some time to implement it properly. It does exactly what I want it to, thanks!